# Prove the 1 point compactification of a T2 space X is a compact space which contains Xas dense subset

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am having trouble doing this theorem.
I have a weak grasp Alexandrov compactification

Here is the version compactification I am
using

Let X be a space not compact and let p
be an object that is not a member of X
The Alexandroff one—point compactification
of X, will be denoted here by X+ and is
defined to be X $\cup $ {p} win topology defined by:

1. nbhds of points of X are the same as in the topology on X
2. U={p} $\cup$ X\K ,K$\cup$ X is compact

Things I know

1. sets in T2 are closed
2. Any Subspace of T2 is T2

**My Try**

To see X+ is compact,let $U_{{n_0}} $ $\in $ U be a set such that p $\in U_{{n_0}} $ By def. of topology of X+ we get
X+\ ${U_n}$ =K where K$\subset $X is
a compact set.
Compactness of K gives us K $\subset$ $\bigcup$ $U_{{n_i}}$for some set
$U_1$,…$U_{{n_i}}$ $\subset$U. So { $U_{{n_i}}$ } is a finite
a subcover for our set.

Since we have a compactification then{p}  $\cup$ (X-K),K$\subset$X is compact set {p} is open .

Ref:(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/971138/1070930)

If X\K is closed,it’s compact, it is T2

Since we have T2 space,it’s Subspace is T2,so closed

From here
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/971839/1070930

I can imply denseness.

I hope my attempt doesn’t look like to much gibberish

Comment: Your proof that $X^+$ is compact, is fine.

Comment: Thanks @Berci .

Comment: I will disagree slightly with Berci. The open cover $U$ of $X+$ is composed of open sets in $X+$, not in $X$. So while you are fine with picking one set in $U$ containing $p$, whose complement is a set $K$ compact in $X$. The remaining sets in $U$ need not be open in $X$ - some or even all of them may also contain $p$ - so you cannot claim they are an open cover of $K$ in $X$. This only requires a small adjustment to your proof to solve, but you do need that adjustment.

Comment: Um,can you help out with that part,please   @PaulSinclair

Comment: Let $V$ be an open set in $X+$ containing $p$. What can you say about $V \setminus \{p\}$ as a subset of $X$?

Comment: V is. an open subset of X+ contained in X . So V$\subset$ X is open?